# How to transfer a conventionally created website/app from MAMP to Meteor

Tags: meteor

I just installed Meteor and it works fine. So my immediate first test was to just copy a little web app I did that uses JQuery, a few javascript libraries and the web audio api and just copy it over to the directory of the session I created and run localhost:3000

I got a bunch of errors and the site doesn't display.

I am wondering if simply moving over a non-Meteor created project has a simple solution (such as a command I need to run) or if the errors that appear have to literally be dealt with one-by-one.

I know this goes against the "point" of using meteor, but maybe I would like to integrate things I've done in the past to a new Meteor project etc.

Heres the error log:

```
Errors prevented startup:
Exception while bundling application:
Error: Can't set DOCTYPE here.  (Meteor sets <!DOCTYPE html> for you) - line 3, file /Users/William/willsjunk/crap/hide&save/Full Working JQuery TUNA Effects!.html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    at html_scanner.scan.parseError (/usr/local/meteor/packages/templating/html_scanner.js:23:14)
    at Object.html_scanner.scan (/usr/local/meteor/packages/templating/html_scanner.js:58:17)
    at /usr/local/meteor/packages/templating/package.js:46:32
    at _.extend.add_file (/usr/local/meteor/app/lib/bundler.js:195:5)
    at self.api.add_files (/usr/local/meteor/app/lib/bundler.js:96:16)
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at Function._.each._.forEach (/usr/local/meteor/app/lib/third/underscore.js:76:11)
    at self.api.add_files (/usr/local/meteor/app/lib/bundler.js:95:11)
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at Function._.each._.forEach (/usr/local/meteor/app/lib/third/underscore.js:76:11)
Your application is crashing. Waiting for file change.
```

Answer (score 0):

I found that the answer is to simply create a public folder and put the non-meteor application in it.

Comment: Remove <!doctype> and <html> from your html files, and note that you will need a router for multipage files,eg. https://atmosphere.meteor.com/package/router